# How to fill a 3D array in Matlab using nested for loops?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fill a 3D array in Matlab using nested for loops. The inner for loop creates a matrix Xtemp of size 1920x16.  The outer for loop should enter each of the 68 Xtemp matrices into a 3D array X.

```
Xtemp = [];  
X = [];
X = zeros(1920,16,68);
for j= 1:68
    for i= 1:16
        Xtemp = [Xtemp illum(:, i, j)];
    end
    X(:,:,j) = Xtemp;
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in proj1_lda (line 25)
    X(:,:,j) = Xtemp;
```

If i remove the outer for loop, I am able to fill only the first matrix (j=1) into the 3D array, so I know the dimensions match and the syntax should be correct.  But when I try to fill in all 68 matrices (or any more than 1), I get the error.  Interestingly, even if I run the for loop more than once but I instead use ***X(:,:,1) = Xtemp;***, this also gives the error.  So it seems that the problem is directly related to running the outer for loop more than once.

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and would appreciate any help.

Comment: how does illum defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first iteration you forgot to clear `Xtemp`.

So after you complete the inner loop the second time, `Xtemp`'s "width" is 32.

You can move the line `Xtemp = []` to the beginning of the outer loop.